# Remove duplicate value available in all order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table with values as shown below

| Sno | orderno | partno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | OCT1 | oRing |
| 101 | OCT1 | Gasket |
| 101 | OCT1 | Case |
| 101 | OCT2 | gRing |
| 101 | OCT2 | Gasket |
| 101 | OCT2 | Cover |
| 101 | OCT3 | Case |
| 101 | OCT3 | Gasket |
| 102 | OCT1 | Gasket |

I want to remove the values that are common in all orders (OCT1,OCT2,OCT3) per Sno. Output should also include orderno as well something like below . Here Gasket is available in all order for 101, so i want to remove it but Case is used in only 2 order out of 3, so i cannot remove it.

| Sno | orderno | partno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | OCT1 | oRing |
| 101 | OCT1 | Case |
| 101 | OCT2 | gRing |
| 101 | OCT2 | Cover |
| 101 | OCT3 | Case |
| 102 | OCT1 | Gasket |

I have tried below code but not working. Please help/suggest

```
select * from mytable where partno not in (
select max(partno) from mytable
group by sno
having count(orderno)=count(partno))
```

Comment: *"I have tried below code but not working"* What does "not working" mean? Though based on your sample data `count(orderno)=count(partno)` will always be true, as there's no `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following approach.  The first CTE finds the distinct number of orders within each `Sno`.  We then also find, in the second CTE, the number of times a product appears within a given `Sno`.  A matching record is one for which the product did not appear in every order.

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT Sno, COUNT(DISTINCT orderno) AS ordernocnt
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY Sno
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t1.*, t2.ordernocnt,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Sno, partno) partcnt
    FROM mytable t1
    INNER JOIN cte1 t2 ON t2.Sno = t1.Sno
)

SELECT Sno, orderno, partno
FROM cte2
WHERE partcnt < ordernocnt OR ordernocnt = 1
ORDER BY Sno, orderno;
```

Comment: just watch out for Sno with just one order, it might get removed

Comment: That's an edge case I didn't even think to cover as the OP's sample data does not reveal it.

Comment: @siggemannen  Thanks for pointing that out. I actual have those cases as well

Comment: `WHERE partcnt < ordernocnt or ordernocnt = 1` should probably fix it

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot @TimBiegeleisen